# Kibana IIS Reverse proxy issue

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, elastic-stack

Reverse proxy for Kibana is not working on Windows Server 2012.
I've followed the steps to configure reverse proxy to Kibana but there seems to be some problem as the reverse proxy Kibana is not loading any data whereas the localhost Kibana is working just fine.
Please go to question on https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/145846/elk-stack-reverse-proxy-configuration for details.

Comment: This helped me a lot: https://www.smbadmin.com/2017/07/securing-kibana-with-iis-reverse-proxy.html. In the "Add Reverse Proxy Rules" dialog I omitted the outbound rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably a cross domain issue, which is disallowed as default in elasticsearch.
add the following to elasticsearch.yml

```
http.cors.enabled : true
http.cors.allow-origin : "*"
http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers : X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, Content-Length
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't seem to work, can you please share the edited elastisearch.yml file or any other possible solution?

Comment: did you restart the elasticsearch service after making the modification? :)

Comment: yes, I restarted all three services, elasticsearch, logstash and kibana, but the output remains same